# Why is this code using .parentNode not working?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the method I’m trying to make. Basically what it’s supposed to do is, when an `<input>` with the `type` of `button` is clicked, it makes the next `<div>` (in this case hard-coded) go from `display: none` to `display: block`. However it’s not working.

```
matchDivs() {
  let showInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
  const inputs = Array.from(showInputs)

  inputs.map(input => {
    if (input.parentNode.getAttribute('class') === 'first-employee') {
      document.querySelector('.second-employee').setAttribute('style', 'display: block')
    }

    return input
  })
}
```

Comment: Consider providing the HTML as well so we can see a [mcve].

Comment: Why are you using `map` if you're not doing anything with the result array?

Comment: honestly no reason really to use a map. just whipped something up real quick

Comment: "*when an <input> with the type of button is clicked, it makes the next <div> [become visible]*" seems to have nothing to do with the code you posted?

Comment: What does `console.log(input.parentNode.getAttribute('class'))` reveal? Is it really exactly `'first-employee'`? Why not try `input.parentNode.classList.contains("first-employee")`? Instead of `document.querySelector('.second-employee')`, shouldn’t it be `input.parentNode.querySelector('.second-employee')`?

Comment: xufox when i console.loged it i got the "first-employee" div, as well as the divs from the children components in that div.

Comment: The code is irrelevant to the question asked. Add more details like from where are you calling matchDivs function and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `if (node.getAttribute('class') === 'first-employee')` this is return:

`class='first-employee' // true`

`class='employee first-employee' // false`

You must use:
`if (node.classList.contains("first-employee"))`:

`class='first-employee' // true`

`class='employee first-employee' // true`

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand your question properly that on button click you want to show/hide DIV tag next to it, which is inside common parent div for both, button and 'second-employee'.

I think below will be helpful.

```js
// For single Div show/hide on button click
let btnMatchDiv = document.querySelector('#btnMatchDivs');

btnMatchDiv.addEventListener('click', matchDivs, true);

function matchDivs() {

  let showInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
  const inputs = Array.from(showInputs)

  inputs.map(input => {

    // Method 1
    // ===========================

    /*if (input.parentNode.getAttribute('class') === 'first-employee') {
      document.querySelector('.second-employee').setAttribute('style', 'display: block')
    }*/


    // Method 2 : you can use new classList method
    // ===========================

    if (input.parentNode.classList.contains('first-employee')) {
      input.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('hidden');
    }

    //return input
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.first-employee {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.second-employee {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#btnMatchDivs {
  padding: 1em 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="first-employee">
  <h2>
    First Employee
  </h2>
  <input type="button" id="btnMatchDivs" value="Toggle Second Employee" />

  <div class="second-employee hidden">
    Second Employee
  </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if you need further help on this.

Thanks,
Jignesh Raval

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to toggle multiple items then you can try below code.

```js
// For multiple Div show/hide on button click
// ===================================

let showInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
const btnInputs = Array.from(showInputs)

// Bind click event to each button input
btnInputs.map(input => {
  input.addEventListener('click', matchDivs, false);
})


function matchDivs(event) {

  let buttonEle = event.currentTarget;

  if (buttonEle.parentNode.classList.contains('first-employee')) {
    buttonEle.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('hidden');
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.first-employee {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.second-employee {
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#btnMatchDivs {
  padding: 1em 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="first-employee">
  <h2>
    First Employee 1
  </h2>
  <input type="button" id="btnMatchDivs" value="Match Divs" />

  <div class="second-employee hidden">
    Second Employee 1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="first-employee">
  <h2>
    First Employee 2
  </h2>
  <input type="button" id="btnMatchDivs" value="Match Divs" />

  <div class="second-employee hidden">
    Second Employee 2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="first-employee">
  <h2>
    First Employee 3
  </h2>
  <input type="button" id="btnMatchDivs" value="Match Divs" />

  <div class="second-employee hidden">
    Second Employee 3
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Thanks,
Jignesh Raval